# Uncrustify: Align all left shifts in all lines

Tags: c++, uncrustify

I try to make uncrustify to go from:

```cpp
    std::cout << "Rho P " <<  this->myThermo->getConst("rhoSolide") << "\n";
    std::cout << "MDB = " << mdb << "\n";
    std::cout << "MDC = " << mdc << "\n";
    std::cout << "T = " << T << "\n";
    std::cout << "P = " << P << "\n";
    std::cout << "Surface = " << S << "\n";
```

to :

```cpp
    std::cout << "Rho P "     << this->myThermo->getConst("rhoSolide") << "\n";
    std::cout << "MDB = "     << mdb                                   << "\n";
    std::cout << "MDC = "     << mdc                                   << "\n";
    std::cout << "T = "       << T                                     << "\n";
    std::cout << "P = "       << P                                     << "\n";
    std::cout << "Surface = " << S                                     << "\n";
```

But so far I failed miserably! Is this even possible, and if so, can I get any hints?

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no such angle align option in Uncrustify as of now.

Only

```
# Whether to align lines that start with '<<' with previous '<<'.
#
# Default: true
align_left_shift                = false    # true/false
```

which for some reason is defaulted be always used